# Can an Xbox360 be plugged into an Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

The Xbox One has a HDMI port for television, so plugging an Xbox 360 into it should work. Is this possible without damaging anything?

Comment: Ummm... what? Why?

Comment: The Xbox One has a quick switch feature to go between movies/store/t.v and the game you are playing.Some people may need to be downloading a movie or watching their collection of downloaded movies from their 360. This means, while playing a game online, waiting for the matchmaking to occur, one can watch their movies or monitor downloads. Even have the 360 in screen for someone else to be playing music or a game on a really small quadrant of the screen. Some people may not want to risk trying this, and since, I have. It works seamlessly, and I don't need a remote.It seems like a good question.

Comment: OK... I think I follow. However, for the sake of clarity, maybe elaborate on the original question a bit. "Plugging my Xbone into my 360 should work right?" just seems a bit... unclear. "Can I put a fork in a toaster?" Yes, but I would advise against it...

Comment: Can anyone answer this with proof from Microsoft so I can suggest this to others?

Comment: Any resource explaining the basics of HDMI should be sufficient in reasoning why an HDMI output on your Xbox 360 will be compatible with the HDMI input on your Xbox One.

Comment: I'm not demanding proof. I am hoping. It was more the question to be answered best.

Comment: _Yo dawg, I heard you like Xbox…._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, plugging the Xbox 360 into the T.V port on your XboxOne will allow you to have both running with sound and visual. Even the Xbox One stereo connector will play the 360's sound through the One's controller(stereo connector connection). " http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360"
Edit; However, video lag makes gaming at fast speeds pretty much unplayable due to the delay on the controller to the video delay of the display lag.

Comment: ... Huh. I didn't expect this to work.

Comment: Please post a video.  I would love to see this.

Comment: You do still have to use the 360 controller: just for completeness.